# Is Supabase compatible with React Native CLI?

Tags: react-native, supabase, react-native-cli, mbaas

I everyone!

I am working on a project that was developed using React Native CLI rather than Expo. I am trying to find documentation related but all I find everywhere is about Expo, never about React Native CLI. My question is simple: Can I use Supabase and configure it to work with a React native CLI app?

I believe I could get it working by applying configurations given in Supabase's documentation for both Kotlin and Swift respectively, but I am fairly new to this and I am quite not confident, the opinion of pros would be very helpful! Also, if it ever isn't, what would you rather recommend as an alternative for relational BaaS?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You should be able to use their React Native library. Expo is React Native under the hood.

Comment: Supabase works just fine with React native CLI.